# Connection Timeout Issue in Stitch Integration

Tags: google-bigquery, amazon-rds, etl, talend, stitch

I am currently facing a persistent issue with a Stitch integration where the connection keeps timing out. It's worth mentioning that I have another integration that is functioning correctly. The production database is hosted on AWS RDS, and the target destination is Google BigQuery.

To establish a connection with a private staging database, I am utilizing an SSL tunnel. Initially, when I start the test connection in the integration, the logs display the databases successfully through the tunnel connection. However, after a certain period of time, the integration starts reporting the following error: socket.timeout: The read operation timed out.

I have been encountering this problem for a few days now and I'm unsure how to proceed. I have verified the accuracy of the hostname and port number, and the connection appears to be established initially. However, it consistently times out after a while.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions to help resolve this issue. Thank you for your assistance!